# How to add text to existing clipboard

Tags: applescript

I have an automator script to create a new folder with subfolders in my current directory.

For example "20200319_video" with one of the subfolders being "Project Files"

I'm able to copy the directory of "user/downloads/20200319_video" to my clipboard, but I would like to add "/Project Files" to the end of it.

Is there any simple way to append text to the clipboard using AppleScript?

Comment: Use: `set the clipboard to (the clipboard) & "/Project Files"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
set the clipboard to (get the clipboard & "/extra bit")
```

Comment: Also, what if I would like to remove a bit of text from the clipboard? like if my clipboard is "users/downloads/photo" how could I remove "/photo" from the clipboard?

Comment: How would the script know which bit of text to remove?

Comment: Oh right. The last bit of text will always be the same amount of characters. So, how to remove the last 26 characters from the clipboard?

Comment: Have a look here https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/ManipulateText.html You can find strings and replace them, get the length of strings, extract substrings or do fairly sophisticated processing.